# TCPServer Error: Permission Denied rails, new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, tcpserver

So I'm getting kind of pissed off at rails now. I started a new project, and this is what I've done so far:

```
rails new blog
cd blog
rake db:create
rails server
```

I know that this should NOT create any errors, and I should be able to get to the "Welcome Aboard" smoke test page, but it does.

[image: Error text]
I have no idea why it's throwing a TCPServer error since the database.yml file is still at default, which is to say it shows as:

[image]

Does anybody have any idea as to why this might be happening? Thank you in advance!